# C++ manipulators with parameters

Tags: c++, manipulators

I'm trying to implement a manipulator with one integer argument.
Except for one little difference I think I'm doing exactly what is told in [this guide](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/33-3.html) and in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935181/how-do-stream-manipulators-with-arguments-work). The only difference is that my operator is a member instead of a free function.

I'll put here just the relevant parts of my code. Some operators and other internal routines will be omitted to keep the code clean. See below:

main.cpp

```
#include "Display.h"

int main()
{
    Display disp;
    disp << position(3) << "some string here";
    // ...
}
```

Display.h

```
struct manip
{
    Display& (*_f)(Display&, int);
    int _i;
    manip(Display& (*f)(Display&, int), int i) : _f(f), _i(i) {}
};

manip position(int pos);

class Display 
{
private:
    int _cursor = 0;
    void cursorPosition(int pos);
public:
    Display& operator<<(manip& m);
    friend Display& setPosition(Display& disp, int pos);
};
```

Display.cpp

```
#include "Display.h"

Display& setPosition(Display& disp, int pos)
{
    disp.cursorPosition(pos);
    return disp;    
}

manip position(int pos)
{
    return manip(setPosition, pos);
}

Display& Display::operator<<(manip& m)
{
    return m._f(*this, m._i);
}
```

The compiler is returning this error message:

> "no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'Display' and 'manip')"

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can replace `Display& operator<<(manip& m);` by `Display& operator<<(const manip& m);`. `position` returns a xvalue and there are no default conversion to a lvalue.

Comment: Yeah! You and Sam are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 disp << position(3) << "some string here";
```

`position(3)` returns a temporary `manip` object, here.

Your overloaded `<<` operator is declared as follows:

```
 Display& operator<<(manip& m);
```

Only a `const` reference can bind to a temporary object. A non-`const` reference will not bind to a temporary object. Your `<<` operator should have a `const manip &` parameter, instead of `manip &`.

This has nothing to do with manipulators that have a parameter. A manipulator without a parameter that's used the same way will also have the same issue, unless it's declared as a static object in global scope (but, in that case, it should also be a `const` object, and will have the same issue as well).